# Tools to help parallelize H.264?

Tags: h.264, modeling, parallel-processing

I am working with H.264 Decoder using Jm reference software. I am looking for some parallelization tools for parallelizing the reference code of H.264 decoder for multiprocessor mapping.Plz suggest as I am  relatively new to this area.

Answer (score 2):

There is no naive way to solve this -- much less a general "automated conversion" approach.

Only a *detailed understanding* of how H.264 works and *careful application of correct parallelization techniques* following a *correctly parallized algorithm* will yield useful results.

H.264, like most Video Formats, relies on *temporal* data frames and effectively only computes "a running delta", which makes this problem *very complex*. This is just *one* of the techniques used to achieve such good compression but the complexity of the format does not stop there: *most* of the data is related in some fashion! (The more dependenent the data is, the less ideal it is suited for parallel processing.)

I would suggest looking for a (non-reference Open Source) implementation that uses threads, if such an implementation exists. Perhaps look at the codec used by VLC? (In the end I suspect more benefit comes from offloading to special hardware-assist modules such as those bundled with modern ATI or NVidia GPUs.)

---

If you are really interested in pursuing this, see...

- [EFFICIENT PARALLELIZATION OF H.264 DECODING WITH MACRO BLOCK LEVEL SCHEDULING](http://www.catanzaro.name/papers/ICME-2007.pdf)
- [Parallel Scalability of H.264](http://alvarez.site.ac.upc.edu/papers/h264_scalability_multiprog_2008.pdf)
- [A Highly Scalable Parallel Implementation of H.264](http://www.hipeac.net/system/files?file=3DWave_Transaction_on_Hipeac.pdf)

...and the million other white papers out there (search for "parallel decode h.264").

Comment: I agree with you about the complexity and i have faced it for quite a long time.I have generated a call graph of the main function to have better understanding of the code and to get some idea of data flow but still when it comes to parallelizing the code, data dependency is too much that it makes parallel processing very difficult. I will try your suggestion.thank you.

Comment: I have read these papers and few more papers on this.it gives me a theoretical understanding of how it has been done but how to implement it is still a doubt..